# Possible to buffer video in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there anyway to buffer video in a Windows Phone 8 app?

I want to create an app that buffers the last 30 seconds or so of video so that the user can tap the screen and get a video file that includes the 30 seconds of video taken prior to their tapping the screen.

I've looked at both the .NET CaptureSource API, and the WP8 only AudioVideoCaptureDevice, both look like they record directly to a file on `IsolatedStorage`:

1. For CaptureSource you use a FileSink object to write an mp4 file of your recorded video.
2. For `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` you can write to a `RandomAccessStream`. WP8 doesn't have the `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` though, so the only way I see to get a `RandomAccessStream` is to create one from a storage file.

For `CaptureSource` you could write your own VideoSink class to buffer your video and use that instead of FileSink, but then you you would be stuck working with the Raw video data, and you'd have to write your own encoder to get it into a formal like an mp4.

Is there anything I'm missing, or is buffering video just not possible on WP8 unless you write your own encoder?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't implement your own `IRandomAccessStream`. Keep swapping between two 30sec-sized buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do This... for various reasons... Maybe you can cache video in memory, making your own implementation of IRandomAccessStream but... as you noted, you need to play in first instance with RAW video, and depending resolution, 30 seconds of raw video and audio can weight more than the total allowed memory for the application so you can had your app closed by the system.

I don't know if you can use a mediaelement to play the video Without showing it to the user and when the user click on play, rewind to Start position and show it to the user, as OS automatically cache streamed videos (This is a happy idea... i don't test This in anyway....)

Sorry for not begin more useful :(